# Show Button after javascript timer has expired

Tags: javascript, timer

How do I show a button after my javascript timer has expired? I am using Visual Studio 2010 and doing it based on a ASP project.

My current code for the timer is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function countDown(sec, elem) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);
  element.innerHTML = "Time left: " + sec + " seconds";
   if (sec < 1) {
    clearTimeout(timer); //clear timeout
    element.innerHTML = 'Time is up!';
    document.getElementById("<%=btnPresentAnswer.ClientID %>").Visible = true;
                }
    sec--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown(' + sec + ', "' + elem + '")', 1000);


                }
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    countDown(5, "status");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `setInterval` instead:

```js
function countDown(sec, elem) {
  var intervalId = undefined;
  var intervalId = setInterval(function(){ 
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Time left: " + sec + " seconds";
    
    if (sec < 1) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      element.innerHTML = 'Time is up!';
      //document.getElementById("<%=btnPresentAnswer.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible"; // ← Uncomment this line!
    }

    sec--;
  }, 1000);
}

countDown(5, "status");
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add **display:none** to the button then if the timer is done then you should replace the display value into block.

Example:
Assuming you have html block here
then this is the button

```
// html
// head
// end head
// body
       <button style="display:none">Test</button> // this will not show in the UI

       <script>
           // your timer function 
           // then if timer is up you should manipulate the display:none turn it into this display:block;
       </script>
//end body
// end html
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
document.getElementById("<%=btnPresentAnswer.ClientID %>").Visible = true;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("<%=btnPresentAnswer.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Assuming you already set the initial visibility to "hidden" somewhere else, for example:

```
<button id="<%=btnPresentAnswer.ClientID %>" style="visibility:hidden">submit</button>
```

You can also use "style.display=block/inline/none" to toggle the show/hide, but there is a small difference between "display" and "visibility":

display=none: the invisible button does NOT take up space;

visibility=invisible: the invisible button does take up space.